# Easiest way to build a project with ant in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ant

I am new to eclipse, please help me understand how can i build any project in eclipse with ant as easily as in is done in netbean like building jar,war,ear or aar for axis2 etc

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse does not use Ant to build projects.

To generate JAR/WAR/etc look into File -> Export menu.

To run Ant targets from an existing buildfile, show Window -> Show View -> Ant and than drag the buildfile into that new Ant view.

Comment: thanks for ur reply, main problem is that how to easily generate ant build file(build.xml or build.property), as doing by hand takes lot or time, so if there is a tool which can do it or a method that can help.

Comment: Right-click on project, choose Export -> General -> Ant buildfiles. But read what it says to you carefully, there are caveats. For example, you cannot edit that file directly.